# Can you expire a key value pair for a hashKey in Redis

Tags: java, redis, key-value, jedis

I want to expire a particular key/value pair set in a hashKey in redis. But redis expires the whole hashKey with all keyValue pairs inside lost. For example i just want to remove Key:666 from seqNu. Using jedis.setex is other option but u cant set a hashKey in it.

```
jedis.hset("seqNu","666",System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
jedis.hset("seqNu","777",System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
jedis.expire("seqNu", 20); // This expires the whole HashKey: seqNu after 20 seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

Redis only expires "whole" keys, not individual elements inside its data structures (i.e.g. a Hash's field or a Set's member). Consider splitting your Hash into multiple string keys (each expirable by itself) or using Sorted Sets as explained here: [Redis: To set timeout for a key value pair in Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105074/redis-to-set-timeout-for-a-key-value-pair-in-set/24105394#24105394)