# How to make item expire in Redis Hash?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am use npm redis (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) in the node server, I have 4 tables. I use `hset` to set key and value of each tables. my code looks like this: `redisClient.hmsetAsync(['my-table1', key, val])`

The problem is: it seems there is nothing called `hexpire` in the world for me to use, and it seems redis does not support each item expire of the list.

Any strategy I can use or any framework or library I can exploit to make my item expire in the Redis Hash?

Thanks

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/expire ?

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk That is for redis key-value, what I really want to expire is expire an item of redis hash table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16545585/4388775

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you expire a key value pair for a hashKey in Redis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959356/can-you-expire-a-key-value-pair-for-a-hashkey-in-redis)

Comment: @ItamarHaber You're the Redis' roadrunner :D

Comment: @matiasfidemraizer - guilty as charged, mip mip! vooosh!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "EXPIRE" the "HSET" child key in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545321/how-to-expire-the-hset-child-key-in-redis)