# How to set expiration time for a Redis hash key in C#?

Tags: c#, redis

I am hashing a value to a key in my Redis.

```
_redis.GetDatabase(0).HashSet("db", "key1" , "value");
```

I also want to set the expiration time of 30 days to this key. I did not find any way to do so.
Are there any possible ways to set an expiration time right after setting the value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "EXPIRE" the "HSET" child key in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545321/how-to-expire-the-hset-child-key-in-redis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example you provided "db" is a **hash-key**, and "key1" is in fact a **sub-key** (see: https://redis.com/ebook/part-1-getting-started/chapter-1-getting-to-know-redis/1-2-what-redis-data-structures-look-like/1-2-4-hashes-in-redis/)

You cannot expire sub-keys (see: [Redis: To set timeout for a key value pair in Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105074/redis-to-set-timeout-for-a-key-value-pair-in-set/24105394#24105394))

**In order to expire hash-key you can use:**

```
_redis.GetDatabase(0).KeyExpire("db", TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// using the async api  
await db.KeyExpireAsync("db", TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
```